# Laravel AWS s3 method return error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I initialize S3 bucket in laravel, I am getting the following error

```
Call to undefined method Aws\Common\Aws::createClient()
```

I use

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"
    }
}
```

Here is the function

```
 public function uploadProductImgAPI(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();


        $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');
        dd($s3);
        return response()->json('upload ok!!');
    }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The doc mentions

> If the AWS facade is registered within the `aliases` section of the
>   application configuration, you can also use the following technique.
>
> ```
> $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');
> ```

else you can use the following

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->createClient('s3');
```